Can a company get out of honoring a subscription by demanding a new terms of service contract?
Say I have a year-long online subscription to the New York Times.
Say that, a few months into the term of my subscription, the New York Times' web site begins to refuse service to me, instead displaying a modal dialog demanding that I form a new contract with them in order to read the newspaper that I have a prepaid subscription for.
If I do not fancy the terms of the new contract and refuse to signal assent, is the New York Times still obligated to provide me access to their online newspaper for the duration of my subscription?

Does the original contract say anything about this? And does it have  clauses for cancellation by the supplier?

Say there is a clause allowing the supplier to cancel the contract. Can just refusing to perform but not actually expressing a desire to cancel the contract "count"?


If I do not fancy the terms of the new contract and refuse to signal assent, is the New York Times still obligated to provide me access to their online newspaper for the duration of my subscription?

You should read the original terms of service. Most likely it has a clause saying that they can change the terms at any time. When they do so, you have a choice of continuing under the new terms, or you can cancel and receive a refund of the remaining portion of your subscription.

I've removed paragraph 2.
